# Cannot fetch internet message headers for some emails

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm using the Microsoft Graph Client for Node.js to fetch email messages. I'm only interested in the headers. The code is working, but recently I got some errors in fetching `internetMessageHeaders` via the API.

For some messages, the API doesn't return any data for this field (and the code wasn't checking for this, hence the errors).

I tried to manually run the queries using POSTMAN. Using `?$select=internetMessageHeaders` as a query param to only fetch the headers. If I remove the query param, I can fetch the message normally (body, etc.).

I haven't been able to find anywhere in the docs why this would happen.
Any ideas on what it's happening?

Edit: Here is the node.js code I am using

```
const MicrosoftGraphClient = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client").Client 

async function fetchEmailMessageHeaders(id, credentials) {
  let client = MicrosoftGraphClient.init({
    authProvider: callback => callback(null, credentials.access_token)
  });
  let req = client.api(id).select("internetMessageHeaders");
  let message = await req.get();
  return message.internetMessageHeaders;
}
```

Sample output (value of message var):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('156751349d3cc68b')/messages(internetMessageHeaders)/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAABcr9US8aH2RIGaOGQZwDg3AAKyfdpk\"",
  "id": "AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1hZWIxLThjZmYALTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA3wcQrEUgfhHoZ0BD2jmyXYHAFyv1RLxofZEgZo4ZBnAODcAAAIBDAAAAFyv1RLxofZEgZo4ZBnAODcAArJaPEcAAAA=",
  "internetMessageHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "Received",
      "value": "from BY2NAM01HT225.eop-nam01.prod.protection.outlook.com (2603:10a6:803:118::39) by VI1PR0301MB2221.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS via VE1PR03CA0050.EURPRD03.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Wed, 10 Apr 2019 11:41:55 +0000"
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

The problem is that for some emails, the message does not contain  `internetMessageHeaders`.

I am using an inbox subscription to receive events for new email messages from Outlook. When an event is received I use the API to retrieve the message and extract headers from it.

API reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Edit2:

Here is an example JSON output of an event that fails to also retrieve headers:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('53e07bf4-bb6a-4a82-a724-37dadfb1cf11')/messages(internetMessageHeaders)/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABQAAADdeU+v2VzbRpZMSJGral7kAAXJkA==\"",
  "id": "AAMkADhmMmVmM2NjLWFhNGMtNDBlYy04NzBkLTg5MmU2OWI0ODU4MgBGAAAAAAALg6E-e6CxRLEbZfrhFaDBBwAzAAMgKF1iTp242t34rFy5AAAAAAAOAAB5l_O62bUUTqTLk6KYrl4sAAGrJcjfAAA="
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. If you can update your question to include the JS you're using, that would help a lot.

Comment: I have added a code snippet to the question.

Comment: What are you getting for results and how do the messages without headers differ from those that have them?

Comment: the API result retuns an object with this format `{
    "@odata.context": "...",
    "@odata.etag": "...",
    "id": ".."
}`. Most API calls also contain an `internetMessageHeaders` key, but for some email, that key is not included.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the actual output. The property names alone are not very helpful. Also, are there any notable differences between emails that include headers and those that don't?

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. I have added an actual output in the original question and some extra info about the code.

Comment: What I'm looking for is the JSON from a message that you expected to include `internetMessageHeaders` but it did not.

Comment: Ok, included a real example of a message that had no headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems internetMessageHeaders are not set when an email is replied to using outlook.office365.com. I'm also not able to see message headers when inspecting the message using Outlook on Mac.